# Cypress cucumber multiple HTML Reports, Is it possible to publish this report in Azure devOps after the pipeline execution?

Tags: html, cucumber, cypress, report, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Is it possible to publish this report in Azure devOps after the pipeline execution?
Azure.yml file contents -

```
` - task: PublishTestResults
           displayName: "Publish Test Results on Azure"
           inputs:
           searchFolder: "./cypress/reports/html-multi-report"
           testResultsFiles: "./cypress/reports/html-multi-report/index.html"
           arguments: reports
           continueOnError: true`
```

I tried but it did not get generated. Maybe someone has already tried doing it?